# having trouble uploading a file via php

Tags: php, file-upload

I am submitting a file with the following html code to a php file. What I want to do is that get that file in php and then set the file as a parameter's value for cURL as postfields and then execute the url, How can I do that?

Here is the html :

```
   <form name="frm" id="frm" method="post" action="fileSubmit.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
   </form>
```

Here is the php

```
<?php 
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) { 
  $curl = curl_init("myDomain/submitFile";); 
  $file = "file=".file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $file); 
  $resp = curl_exec($curl); 
  curl_close($curl); 
} 
?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the problem? show the php code

Comment: please be more clear on your question show the code and where is the problem?

Comment: Here is the php code that I am trying to upload the file. Am I doing anything wrong?

<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{
    $curl = curl_init("http://myDomain/submitFile");
    $file = "file=".file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $file);
    $resp = curl_exec($curl); 
    curl_close($curl);
}
?>

Comment: My doubt is that am I sending the file properly as the value for the parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]
```

instead, until you move the uploaded file it is stored in a temporary location

Comment: Thanks Gabriel,

Is there any way that I can send the files content as a stream in PHP. I saw the PHP stream thing, but

Comment: The problem is that I am sending a file to a php code from html page by <input type="file">. I want to send the file like https://myDomain/fileSubmit?file=<uploaded file from HTML code>. Can anyone figure how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There are several things here that need fixing... 
Change your code to:

```
$postParams = array(
    "@file" => $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
    "name"  => $_FILES["file"]["name"]
);
$curl = curl_init("http://remote-site.com/upload-script.php"); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
// curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); // yes, this must be commented out. It will stop the upload otherwise.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1); // post must be enabled.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postParams); 
$resp = curl_exec($curl); 
curl_close($curl);
```

Tested here and works perfectly.